# Erro Sintaxe! Java + XML

Tags: java, xml, sqlite, tdd

1. O banco de dados deverá ser implementado no SQLite e deverá ter as tabelas;
   tbprevisao e tbcidade
2. O sistema deverá manter os dados das cidades já consultadas na tbcidade para evitar ter de buscar no serviço do CPTEC o código da cidade a cada nova consulta da mesma cidade;
3. O sistema deverá manter os dados de previsão já consultados na tbprevisao e a data de atualização no campo
   tbcidade.atualizacao. Se no momento da consulta a data de atualização da previsão for diferente de hoje, todos os
   dados de previsão da cidade deverão ser removidos da tbprevisao e novos dados deverão ser buscados no serviço
   do CPTEC;
4. O sistema deverá ter uma interface gráfica ou por linha de comando para o usuário fornecer o nome de uma cidade
   ou parte do nome. Na sequência o sistema deverá exibir como resultado a previsão do tempo para os próximos 7
   dias - formada por data (dd/mm/aaaa), tempo, IUV, temperatura mínima e máxima. No caso do nome fornecido
   pelo usuário resultar em vários nomes, por exemplo, São José, o sistema deverá exibir somente o 1º resultado da
   consulta.

URL para buscar a previsão da cidade com id = 4963
http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/XML/cidade/7dias/4963/previsao.xml

URL para buscar o código da cidade
http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/XML/listaCidades?city=sao%20jose

Tentei criar a conexão da seguinte maneira!

```
package aula;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;



public class BancoDados {

    public Connection conectar() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Connection conexao = null;
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        File bd = new File("bdprevisao.db");
        /* verifica se o arquivo do BD existe na raiz do projeto */
        if( !bd.exists() ){
        /* cria o arquivo do BD na raiz do projeto e cria uma conexão para o BD */
        conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:bdprevisao.db");
        /* como o BD não existe então é necessário criar as tabelas */
        //createTableCidade();
        //createTablePrevisao();
        }
        else{
        /* cria uma conexão com o BD */
        conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:bdprevisao.db");
        }
        conexao.setAutoCommit(false);
        return conexao;
        }

    public boolean createTableCidade(Connection conexao) throws SQLException{
        Statement stmt = conexao.createStatement();
         String sql = "create table if not exists tbcidade( " +
         "id int not null," +
         "nome varchar(64) not null," +
         "uf char(2) not null," +
         "atualizacao varchar(10)" +
         ")";
         stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
         stmt.close();
         return true;
    };

    public boolean createTablePrevisao(Connection conexao) throws SQLException{

         Statement stmt = conexao.createStatement();
         String sql = "create table if not exists tbprevisao( " +
         "id int not null," +
         "dia date not null," +
         "tempo char(3) not null," +
         "minima float not null," +
         "maxima float not null," +
         "iuv float not null," +
         "primary key (id, dia)," +
         "foreign key (id) references tbcidade(id) " +
         ")";
         stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
         stmt.close();
         return true;
        }



    public boolean insertCidade(Cidade cidade, Connection conexao) throws SQLException{
        // o campo atualizacao irá receber o valor padrão, ou seja, null 
        String sql = "insert or ignore into tbcidade(id,nome,uf) values(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setInt(1, cidade.getId() );
        stmt.setString(2, cidade.getNome() );
        stmt.setString(3, cidade.getUf() );
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();
        conexao.commit();
        return true;
        }


    public List<Cidade> selectCidade(String sql, Connection conexao) throws SQLException{
        Statement stmt = conexao.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        List<Cidade> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        Cidade cidade;
        while ( rs.next() ) {
        cidade = new Cidade();
        cidade.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        cidade.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
        cidade.setUf(rs.getString("uf"));
        cidade.setAtualizacao(rs.getString("atualizacao"));
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conexao.commit();
        return lista;
        }

    public String getXMLCidade(String cidade) throws Exception {
        String charset = java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name();
        String linha, resultado = "";
        String urlListaCidade = "http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/XML/listaCidades?city=%s";


//codifica os parâmetros
    String parametro = String.format(urlListaCidade, URLEncoder.encode(cidade, charset) );
    URL url = new URL(parametro);
    URLConnection conexao = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conexao.getInputStream()));
    while((linha = reader.readLine()) != null){
    resultado += linha;
    }
    return resultado;
    }

public Cidade[] xmlToObjectCidade(String xml) throws Exception {
     StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
     /* a base do XML é uma marcação de nome cidades */
     JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Cidades.class);
     Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
     Cidades cidades = (Cidades) un.unmarshal(sr);
     return cidades.getCidade();
    }
```

}

Classe cidade

```
package aula;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
@XmlRootElement(name = "cidade")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"nome", "uf", "id"})
public class Cidade {
 @XmlElement(name = "id")
 private Integer id;
 @XmlElement(name = "nome")
 private String nome;
 @XmlElement(name = "uf")
 private String uf;
private String atualicao;

public void setId(int int1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.id = int1;
}

public void setAtualizacao(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.atualicao =  string;
}

public void setUf(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.uf =  string;
}

public void setNome(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.nome =  string;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public String getUf() {
    return uf;
}

public String getAtualicao() {
    return atualicao;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setAtualicao(String atualicao) {
    this.atualicao = atualicao;
}


}
```

Classe cidades

```
package aula;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "cidades")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"cidade"})

public class Cidades {
 @XmlElement
 private Cidade[] cidade;

public Cidade[] getCidade() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Está apresentando o seguinte erro

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 7 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
A propriedade atualicao está presente, mas não foi especificada em @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String aula.Cidade.getAtualicao()
        at aula.Cidade
        at private aula.Cidade[] aula.Cidades.cidade
        at aula.Cidades
Há duas propriedades com o nome "id"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.Integer aula.Cidade.getId()
        at aula.Cidade
        at private aula.Cidade[] aula.Cidades.cidade
        at aula.Cidades
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.Integer aula.Cidade.id
        at aula.Cidade
        at private aula.Cidade[] aula.Cidades.cidade
        at aula.Cidades
Há duas propriedades com o nome "nome"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String aula.Cidade.getNome()
        at aula.Cidade
        at private aula.Cidade[] aula.Cidades.cidade
        at aula.Cidades
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String aula.Cidade.nome
        at aula.Cidade
        at private aula.Cidade[] aula.Cidades.cidade
        at aula.Cidades
Há duas propriedades com o nome "uf"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String aula.Cidade.getUf()
        at aula.Cidade
        at private aula.Cidade[] aula.Cidades.cidade
        at aula.Cidades
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String aula.Cidade.uf
        at aula.Cidade
        at private aula.Cidade[] aula.Cidades.cidade
        at aula.Cidades
A classe tem duas propriedades do mesmo nome "nome"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String aula.Cidade.getNome()
        at aula.Cidade
        at private aula.Cidade[] aula.Cidades.cidade
        at aula.Cidades
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String aula.Cidade.nome
        at aula.Cidade
        at private aula.Cidade[] aula.Cidades.cidade
        at aula.Cidades
A classe tem duas propriedades do mesmo nome "uf"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String aula.Cidade.getUf()
        at aula.Cidade
        at private aula.Cidade[] aula.Cidades.cidade
        at aula.Cidades
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String aula.Cidade.uf
        at aula.Cidade
        at private aula.Cidade[] aula.Cidades.cidade
        at aula.Cidades
A classe tem duas propriedades do mesmo nome "id"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.Integer aula.Cidade.getId()
        at aula.Cidade
        at private aula.Cidade[] aula.Cidades.cidade
        at aula.Cidades
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.Integer aula.Cidade.id
        at aula.Cidade
        at private aula.Cidade[] aula.Cidades.cidade
        at aula.Cidades

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at aula.BancoDados.xmlToObjectCidade(BancoDados.java:128)
    at aula.Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

meu arquivo do main se precisarem!

```
BancoDados banco = new BancoDados();

        try {
            Connection conexao = banco.conectar();
            banco.createTableCidade(conexao);
            banco.createTablePrevisao(conexao);

            //List<Cidade> teste = banco.selectCidade(sql, conexao);

            try {
                String testando = banco.getXMLCidade("sao jose");

                System.out.println(testando);

                banco.xmlToObjectCidade(banco.getXMLCidade("sao jose"));


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `propOrder` é baseado no campo do atributo/propriedade que você declara. Recomendo você explicitamente indicar se deseja usar o nome do atributo ou o nome do campo.

Se é do seu interesse usar o nome do campo, adicione a anotação: `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` na sua classe.

Referências:

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxbs-xmltype-and-proporder.html
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html